# Simple Filter Erlang

Tags: erlang

Trying to figure out this simple Erlang filter question. It is supposed to take a predicate, and a list and return a modified version of the first list with all of the elements that return true for the predicate.

```
-module(filter).
-export([filterlist/2]).

-spec filterlist(fun((T) -> boolean()), [T]) -> [T].

filterlist (P, LL) -> lists:filter(fun(X) -> X == P end, LL).
```

I can't get it to work. It only returns and empty list [].

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`P` is a predicate, which means a function which takes a value ans returns a boolean value.

So instead of writing `X == P`, you should write `P(X) == true`, which is simply written `P(X)`.

The problem is, now you've simply called `lists:filter`:

```
filterlist(P, LL) -> lists:filter(P, LL).
```

If you're looking to filter a list with a predicate, start with this:

```
filterlist(_, [])          -> [],
filterlist(P, [Elem|Rest]) ->    % ...
```

Where the `%...` either keeps the `Elem`, or skips it, then calls `filterlist(P, Rest)`

Answer (score 2):

If you would not like use `lists:filter/2` library function in way (your function is exactly what `lists:filter/2` does)

```
filterlist(P, L) -> lists:filter(P, L).
```

you can use list comprehention

```
filterlist(P, L) -> [ X || X<-L, P(X) ].
```

or write it yourself

```
filterlist(_, []) -> [];
filterlist(P, [H|T]) ->
  case P(H) of
    true -> [H|filterlist(P, T)];
    false -> filterlist(P, T)
  end.
```